# How to calculate op amp output voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, resistors, voltage-divider

I have the following circuit:

[image]

If I feed the circuit with 10 V all I get is about 8.2 V when VFD > 3.3 V. How is the resistor divider calculated (R94 and R95 + RV1) so I can get a voltage as close as possible to the input voltage of 10 V?

Comment: With a 10v supply and an LM358, 8.2V is about as close as it's possible to get. That's as high as an LM358 can go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If I feed the circuit with 10v all I get is about 8.2V when VFD > 3.3v*

The typical output voltage of an [LM358](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) is about 2 volts lower than the positive supply rail. Given that the positive supply rail is only 10 volts then, the output will be limited to +8.0 volts or maybe a bit lower worst case (only +6 or +7 volts depending on op-amp output load).

Additionally, the input circuits of the LM358 are also limited in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The LM358 does not have rail-to-rail output- you can expect a couple volts drop depending on loading, temperature etc.

You can either give it a higher voltage supply or use an op-amp with R-R output instead of the LM358.